# My NodeJs gives error for unhandledPromise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, atom-editor, nodemon

[image: This is the erroe]

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        tours: newTour,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: err,
    });
  }
};
```

Everything is running until I added async function here.what might be the reason?

Comment: Is the `.json` method synchronous? Is an exception being thrown in the `catch` statement?

Answer (score 1):

what goes on inside Tour.create?

Could it be you are calling `Promise.reject()` inside a `new Promise((resolve,reject){...})` instead of using `reject()`?

this next code for both reject and resolve cases in my "bla" function:

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const newTour = await bla();
        res.status(201).json({
          status: "success",
          data: {
            tours: newTour,
          },
        });
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          status: "fail",
          message: err,
        });
      }
});

    
    let bla=()=>{
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        //resolve("yay");
        reject("I have my reasons");
      });
    }
```

Ill try to explain what I suspect is going on-
but its hard to know without seeing the code:

```
let create = ()=>{
      // option 1. returns a new promise that resolves - your catch should work 
      Promise.resolve("great success");

      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        // option 2. creates a new promise in the new promise, which would explain the situation you described
        Promise.reject("I need to be handled too - but im not");

        // option 3. handles the locally created and rejected promise
        Promise.reject("I need to be handled too").catch(x => console.log("handled"));

        // option 4. rejects and is caught in the createTour function that called us - your catch should work  
        reject("I have my reasons");

       // option 5. another function you call rejects and is not handled - would also cause what you described, for the same reason
       let result = await func();
      });
    }
```

try to see if you have some sort of option 5 or 2 going on - it creates a promise in the promise, that rejects (and is not handled)..

also, notice that instead of using a full try{..}catch{..} around your code you could use

```
await Tour.create().catch(err => ...);
```

(like in option 2) and handle rejects specifically

in case you wanna read more:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-implement-a-promise-in-javascript-9238aec9c17b

Comment: does it make any difference that bla function is user defined and create is predefined.

Comment: Where and how is Tour.create defined? I assumed it was in your code.. if it's just in another file it should make no difference

Comment: I edited to show different ways the reject could be caused and what I think is going on based on what you posted.. it may be the inside create you call another method that returns a reject without handling it..

Comment: There was a function before createTour, that was causing problem so I had to deleted it.